# Symlink User Folders - Can I keep original Sidebar Icons?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, icon, symlink

I have my user folders (Music, Movies and Pictures) stored on an external drive, so I used terminal to delete the existing user folders on the boot drive then created symlinks to these folders and placed then in my user directory.

They function correctly but when I drag them into the sidebar I can only see folder icons, not the original music, movies and Pictures icons. How can I keep the original icons I'm the sidebar whilst using symlinks to my user directory folders?

Comment: Jash Jacob posted the answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91460/restoring-finder-icon

Answer (score 1):

I've already posted the solution on a previous question with a similar problem.

[Restoring finder icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91460/restoring-finder-icon)