# How to restore Yosemite finder sidebar icons after changing folders with symlinks

Tags: macos

After I installed on my mac a second drive I figured out it was a good idea to use the old HD for storage. So I symlinked `~/Downloads`, `~/Documents`, `~/Music`, `~/Pictures` and `~/Movies` in order for them to be actually located in the old HD, while I'm using the new SSD as a startup disk.
Everything works *remarkably* ok, except, now the icons in the finder sidebar for those folders are the default ones:

[image]

Even though in the finder preference the icons are ok:

[image]

I already tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91460/restoring-finder-icon) but I was only able to restore both the actual folder icons, but not the icons in the sidebar!

Comment: did you try to - Select on of the folders and hit Command + I. Go to the top left corner where there is an icon and select it and hit delete. This should delete the old icon and will be replaced with the new one.

Comment: Yes, just tried but it restores the general blank folder icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that, unfortunately, you can't do this.  See this answer:
[How come Dropbox gets an icon in Finder sidebar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83152/how-come-dropbox-gets-an-icon-in-finder-sidebar)

and this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380562/adding-buttons-to-finder-toolbar